# How to install latest pandas on old Debian Linux?

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I need to install the latest version of **pandas on an old Debian Gnu/Linux 8 (jessie) server**.

`apt-get install python-pandas` installs `pandas==0.14.1` (instead of `0.23.4`) and `numpy==1.8.2` (instead of `1.15.2`).

Is it possible to update to the latest version, possibly without compiling the sources?

**Here the full solution (for the lazy ones)**

```
virtualenv env         # to create an environment
. env/bin/activate     # activate it
pip install -U pip     # to upgrade to the latest version
pip install pandas==0.23.4
```

If installing pandas takes ages like in my case, because of problems with compilation (missing libs) use instead:

`pip install pandas==0.23.4 --no-build-isolation`

`pip` update has been necessary because my previous version (`1.5.6`) didn't support `--no-build-isolation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Debian package of *anything* will typically be far behind any latest version. Debian packages a stable version and will not generally update except for security updates between releases.  And you are asking about an *old* Debian version!

There are two workarounds: Find an unofficial Debian package ("backports" is a good place to start) or don't rely on Debian packaging at all.

Typically for Python, you want the latter -- simply install with `pip` into a `virtualenv` the precise version you want.

Comment: Here's a list of unofficial PPAs for Numpy for Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=python-numpy -- change the search to find similar packages for Pandas.